# Getting the current Instant in a specific TimeZone

Tags: java, scala, java-8, java-time

I have tried to get the current Instance on a specific timeZone but it does not work as expected. Any idea on how to do this ?

Here is what i did:

```
Instant.now(Clock.system(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
```

However the instant time returned is always UTC. I changed many time the ZoneID and it is always wrong. Please advise.

EDIT:

I'm interacting with an application that generate log with timeStamp and i need to operate over those event. For instant if I start my program with a specific TimeStamp it should start reading event from that TimeStamp. While my laptop is in the same TimeZone as the application that generate those event, when i get Instant.Now() i seem to be in UTC. While the application generate timeStamp according to the TimeZone in which we are. I want the clock of my program to be the same as the one in the Server.

The application generate timestamp of the form 2016-08-04T18:17:51Z

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have an `Instant` in a specific time zone, since an `Instant` doesn't have the notion of a timezone, only the count of millis since the Epoch. So what exactly do you want to do / have?

Comment: In Java 8 time api an Instant is supposed to represent a single instantaneous point on the time-line. Now the concept of timezone comes into play when you try to convert this point in time into human's concept of Date and Time.

Comment: Well, I'm interacting with an application that return some event with a timestamp, I need to operate on those event according to their timeStamp.

Comment: What is the purpose of Instant.now(clock) ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon, `Clock` provides two things - the time-zone and the current instant. In the case of `Instant`, only the current instant is used. (The two parts of `Clock` could have been two different interfaces, but we judged that the separation didn't add enough value)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Instant` are not Timezone aware. If you need a time zone aware timestamp, you should use `ZonedDateTime`.

Check out [`ZonedDateTime.now(timezone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-%5D) which will use the provided timezone. To use the machine's default timezone, use [`ZonedDateTime.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now--)

If you want to parse a ZonedDateTime and override the timezone, you can use [`ZonedDateTime.withZoneSameLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameLocal-java.time.ZoneId-) or [`ZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-) depending on your need.

Comment: thank you. I got confused with the timestamp of the system, they are actually UTC. I made a mistake but, thanks for the input, it helps clarifying everything