# Java ZonedDateTime.toInstant() moves to UTC

Tags: java

I want simply to move an Instant moment to another time zone.

for example

`2020-04-08 23:59:59.999 UTC` -> to `Europe/Sarajevo[UTC+1]`

should result at:
`2021-04-09 00:59:59.999 UTC`

it does not return this

```
 dateVal.atZone(operatorTimeZone).toInstant()
```

returns wrong value.

but  `dateVal.atZone(operatorTimeZone)` returns the right value.

unfortunantly I need the response to be Instant.

How can this be fixed?

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: ```Instant``` is not Time Zone aware. Check this question for details: [Getting the the current Instant in a specific TimeZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774734/getting-the-the-current-instant-in-a-specific-timezone)

Comment: *The Instant class in the Java date time API (java.time.Instant) represents a specific moment on the time line. The instant is defined as an offset since the origin (called an epoch).* There is no purpose of Zone because you may see it a duration from the origin, wherever you are on earth this is the same

Comment: "should result at: 2021-04-09 00:59:59.999 UTC" - no, it shouldn't. It sounds like you've misunderstood what Instant represents. I suspect you actually want to start with 2020-04-08 23:59:59.999 as a `LocalDateTime`, and convert *that* to the Europe/Sarajevo time zone, then convert that to an Instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to want to do is to add the timezone's offset at the instant `dateVal`, to that instant. This can be done by getting the offset and adding directly:

```
ZoneOffset offset = operatorTimeZone.getRules().getOffset(i);
Instant newInstant = dateVal.plusSeconds(offset.getTotalSeconds());
```

Another way is to use [`withZoneSameLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameLocal-java.time.ZoneId-), though I think this doesn't show the intent as clearly, and is more like a "trick".

```
Instant newInstant = dateVal
                        .atZone(operatorTimeZone)
                        .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                        .toInstant();
```

---

That said, the more I think about this, the more this looks like an XY problem. Representing the result as a `ZonedDateTime` rather than an `Instant` is probably what you *really* should do.

Comment: This is basically working round the OP using the wrong data type as a starting point. `withZoneSameLocal` is *usually* a code smell, as it very rarely (IMO) represents a semantically-sensible operation.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, as thought more about this, I started to think it's an XY problem... Your comment came just as I was editing.